# Dual IP problem in PPP adapter in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I am running my ATM machine with a Telco's CDMA network. They are using PPP to get the IP. But some times I get Dual IP in the same PPP adapter. In this scenario I can't get my Server from the particular ATM machine.

```
PPP adapter CBL:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0   
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0  
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.18.11

PPP adapter CBL:        
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . 
PP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.18.11
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255    
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.18.11
```

Does anybody have any idea how can I get one IP consistently?

Comment: Duel or dual? I'm confused.

Comment: can you double-check the second adapter details?  particularly the "DNS Suffix" and "PP Address" lines.  is that adapter really set to be its own gateway?  also, the output of `route` or `route print` while in the problem state might be helpful.

Comment: Hello.
there is no second adapter.. In one PPP adapter i am geeing Two IP address when the line disconnected or line is droped. 

Chk the link : http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?82b3b07f96.jpg